# How to perform unassigned sum with short variable with out converting in to integer in java

Tags: java

My requirement is to perform unassigned sum  with short variables in java with out converting in to integer.

Please suggest is it possible to perform unassigned sum or not.

Comment: What did you mean by "unassigned sum"?

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't *have* an addition operator for `short` values. If you look at [JLS 15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) (Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types) you'll see that one of the first things that happens is:

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§[5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).

That will always convert `short` values into `int`, `float`, `long` or `double` values, depending on the other operand.

Basically, to perform 16-bit addition, you let the compiler convert both operands into 32 bits, do the addition, and then cast back:

```
(short) (a + b)
```

... being aware that this may lose information due to overflow when casting.